# OpenFileDialog error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

This is my code on click of SAVE button:

```
OpenFileDialog myOpenfileDialog = new OpenFileDialog(); 
        myOpenfileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        myOpenfileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        myOpenfileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (myOpenfileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileUploadData.SaveAs(myOpenfileDialog.FileName);//my file upload control taking the path to save the file to the selected location
        }
```

I am getting this exception :

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
>   this is a threadStateException

Comment: You've tagged the question with asp.net *and* winforms, but with no clarification of whether this is a web app where you're somehow trying to use Windows Forms controls, or a Windows Forms app. Please add more detail to the question.

Comment: This is an asp.net application only where i am using System.Windows.Forms to make use of the class OpenFileDialog

Comment: The problem is that you can't. Winforms is not for ASP.NET but for Winforms applications.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the message seems reasonably clear to me - you need to be using an STA thread. If you're writing a Windows Forms application, you do this by making sure that your `Main` method is decorated with an attribute like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

If you're writing an ASP.NET application, you shouldn't be trying to use a Windows Forms control in your code in the first place. I mention this because you've tagged your question with *both* `winforms` and `asp.net` - you shouldn't be mixing the code for the two.

Comment: @Jon : You keep beating me to answers, i'm outta here...see you on twittter.

Comment: @Jon : This an asp.net application and not win form. I have used System.Windows.Forms in my application so that i should be able to access OpenFileDialog class and use it to browse the location to save the file.

Comment: @NayeemKhan: don't mix. What is the objective of using OpenFileDialog in the first place? Perhaps you should be asking how can I achieve the functionality of an OpenFileDialog class implementation in asp.net.

Comment: @deostroll, oh yes, i want the functionality in asp.net. I want a window where my client can browse a folder in HardDisk to save the file, on click of SAVE button

Comment: @ace: He beats everyone, including me. After all he is Jon Skeet :)

Comment: @nayeemkhan: Assuming you are trying to download a file from the internet (or your web page), usually browsers have the capability of saving the file to the disk. However different browsers handle it differently. For e.g. in IE, on the download dialog box, you can save to a specific location on your disk, where as on firefox it defaults to the location set as per your preferences. Browsers innately have the ability of saving files to disk, however I don't think you can control *where the file gets saved* via server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Your Exception is pretty self-explanatory, just mark the Main method with STAThread Attribute

EDIT:

Considering that this is an ASP.NET application, then you need to use the following in your ASPX page to show a file open kind of dialog to let user select a file, i assume that is what your intention is:

```
<input type=file name="fileToUpload">

  OR

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

More info about FileUpload control :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Comment: This is an ASP.NET Application. There is no main() in the winforms sense.

Comment: Well in ASP.NET application there is no use of OpenFileDialog, so its understood its a winform application.

Comment: Dear All, this is an asp.net application, where i am making use of System.Windows.Forms so that i can use OpenFileDialog class.

Comment: OpenFileDialog won't work in an asp.net application, so forget about it. Use need to use html input tag type=file to show a file open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be used for ASP.NET. Only for Winforms.
Only Winforms can use the single thread apartment model.